# do I need to parallelize or multithread my application

Tags: c++, hardware

I have some conceptual confusion regarding the terms `thread` and `core`, and how they relate to the programs that I write and execute on my home computer. Say I am running the following program on my machine, which a [quad-core motherboard](http://ark.intel.com/products/52210/Intel-Core-i5-2500K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz) with four threads

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int long long num = 1E15;
    while(num--)
    {
        cout << num << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I want this program to utilize more than a single core, does my program need to support multithreading or does it need to be parallelized? Or will it be the same in my case, since my CPU has 1 thread per core?

Comment: This program is a very bad example since it can't be parallelised (and even if it could be, it would be completely useless since the performance is I/O bound).

Comment: Have you done any research at all about this subject? I know that a similar question was asked here within the last couple of days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Cores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) are a hardware concept. [Loosely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) [speaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar), when we say that a CPU has `n` cores, we mean that it can do `n` things at the same time.

[Threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) are a software concept. It refers to a sequence of instructions that can be managed independently by the operating system scheduler. Typically, a [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) consists of one or more threads, although in [some operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) the distinction between processes and threads is somewhat blurred.

At any given moment in time, a core is either idle or is executing a thread.

Your example currently has a single thread. Therefore it cannot make use of more than a single core. To use multiple cores, you would need to introduce multiple threads or multiple processes. This can be described as *parallelizing* your program, although it is worth noting that using multiple threads/processes [is not the only way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) to parallelize a program.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, `multithreading` will *force* the OS to use more than one core of the CPU. But this is always OS dependendent. The scheduler of the OS is responsible for distributing the threads according to its policy.